# Can I use my "free object interaction" between the multiple attacks of my Attack action?

Tags: dnd-5e, attack, actions, action-economy

Say I'm a fighter and have the Extra Attack feature, which lets me make multiple attacks as part of a single action. Can I make one attack, interact with an object using the free interaction, then make my second attack?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Comment: Closely related: [Can I draw a weapon between attacks?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/143777/33569). Also: [Can you take a “free object interaction” while incapacitated?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/143494/33569), [By RAW, can you use your free object interaction while taking the “Use an Object” action?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/158079/33569), [Can you use your free object interaction while restrained?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/174164/33569)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

#### Yes, your object interaction may occur during your move or action.

The rules for your object interaction are found in the section [Other Activity on Your Turn](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#OtherActivityonYourTurn):

> You can also interact with one object or feature of the environment for free, *during either your move or your action.*

*During your action* seems clear enough. Between the two attacks of your attack action is definitely *during your action*.

We can see this further demonstrated in the rules for moving between your attacks. We have already observed that that object interation may be taken during your move, but also see in the rules that you may move *between your attacks*:

> If you take an action that includes more than one weapon attack, you can break up your movement even further by moving between those attacks. For example, a fighter who can make two attacks with the Extra Attack feature and who has a speed of 25 feet could move 10 feet, make an attack, move 15 feet, and then attack again.

Naturally, an object interaction may be taken during that move, which can happen between attacks.

Comment: Assuming you don't need to use your free object interaction to enable the attacks themselves; for example changing weapons, drawing a thrown weapon, etc.  This would of course still be allowed as during your action, but it would prevent you from using the free object interaction _on something else_.

Comment: This is extra correct because the rules allow the interaction as part of the character's movement and [movement can occur between attacks](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#MovingBetweenAttacks)

Comment: @Kirt While you're correct, using your free object interaction to draw a second throwing weapon might be the single most common reason this question comes up at a table.